# Mount remote disk with Java via SSH

Tags: java, ssh, sshfs

Using Java is possible to mount a remote disk via SSH? 
I saw that exist for Windows systems such as Dokan, win-SSH-FS or anything, but I would need to be able to map the remote disk through Java.

I have already completed part of the application in Java but as the last thing I need that the login process of my application  perform also mount the disk. Unfortunately I can not find anything ....

I use Java because it may be fine for both Windows and Linux.

Ideas?

Comment: It's possible to open a SSH shell to a remote machine and execute commands, which would allow you to execute a mount command with the context of the remote machine. Have a look for jsch for examples

Comment: Define "mount the disk"? You could write to the remote system, but implementing an OS level file-system bridge from Java would not be my first choice.

Comment: probably he/she's looking for something like sshfs support for apache commons vsf. Interesting question, indeed.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: already tested with jsch, but does not mount the remote disk, you can send the commands as an ftp session.


Elliott Frisch: yeah, right, mount the disk to be able to be accessed for read / write. Exactly as the programs mentioned above.


If nothing exists for Java. you know some library for C # / VB.NET?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) helps mount a remote file system hosted via a ssh server onto a local machine

Here is a [Sshfs Java Implementation](https://github.com/lucastheisen/jsch-nio)

```
Map<String, Object> environment = new HashMap<String, Object>();
environment.put( "defaultSessionFactory", defaultSessionFactory );
environment.put( "watchservice.inotify", true );
uri = new URI( scheme + "://" + username + "@" + hostname + ":" + port + sshPath );
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem( uri, environment );
```

and then you can treat the files as local files and operate on them.